# When I import an excel file the character column comes out with numbers

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xls, readxl

I am uploading an excel database to R and some data from the column that has characters appears with numbers. This is my code.

```
p <- read_excel("Raw_Data/31-01-2018.xls", sheet = 10,range = "A8:E24")
```

This is the output.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO4WK.png)

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you specify the `col_types = "text"`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work...

Comment: Did you specify it as "text"

Comment: You may also check with `openxlsx::read.xlsx`

Comment: yes, like this ``` p <- read_excel("Raw_Data/31-01-2018.xls", sheet = 10,range = "A8:E24",  col_types = c("text","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"))```

Comment: But the database is in .xls format.

Comment: You meant the first column values like 4173 should be characters?  Can you try with `read.xlsx`

Comment: If it is `.xls`, try with `read_xls`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work..

Comment: Can you able to post a subset of the file in github for testing

Comment: This is the file https://github.com/brianamaya01/Test-Raw_data/raw/master/31-01-2018.xls.

Comment: It could be an encoding issue

Comment: and how could it be solved? I think readxl handles UTF-8.
Or will the problem be with the database?

Comment: Are you okay with other packages?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `xlsx` package. It looks like an issue with the merged cells. With the next code you are able to load it and then assign a name for the merged cells:

```
library(xlsx)
p <- read.xlsx("31-01-2018.xls",sheetIndex =  10,startRow = 8,endRow = 24,colIndex = c(1:7),encoding = 'UTF-8')
names(p)[1] <- 'Modalidad delictiva'
names(p)[c(6,7)]<-c('Total','Participación %')
```

Output (Image):

[image]

Comment: If I work with that file, but the problem is that there are 72 files with .xls and .xlsx format and the lapply doesn't work for me, would you know how to solve it?

Comment: `CRIMES <-lapply(filelist,function(i){
        y = str_subset(excel_sheets(i), "^9.")
        x<- lapply(y,function(j){
                data <- read.xlsx(filelist,
                               sheetName =  j ,startRow = 8,endRow = 24,colIndex = c(1:7),encoding = 'UTF-8')
                colnames(data)<- N_CRIMES
                data$DATE <- i
                data
        }
        )
})`

Comment: I would suggest first try loding all the sheets in one file. You can use a vector like `1:n` to place in sheetindex, which is better than using sheetname. Then you could set a macro `lapply()`. That is my suggestion. I have loaded files with many sheets using that package. First test with one file and use index instead of names.

Comment: Ok, I will follow your suggestion and if something I can tell you about the process, thank you all for your help.

Comment: @BrianAmaya Yeah sure!